Google API with AWS Lambda
I tried to connect OpenAI Custom GPT Action with AWS Lambda to create a Google Docs in template and replace all the placeholder inside the template. I used two lambda functions to do the Google Docs creation, the functions have no log errors and everything is good. the problem is when I check the Google Drive, no docs are created. Another problem is regarding the GPT Action, even if the output from the GPT is exactly the same with the test event I used in Lambda, it keeps showing "No data provided"
This is the first lambda function connecting to GPT action and will call the second lambda function.
import json
import logging
import boto3

# Setup basic logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Initialize the boto3 client for Lambda at the global scope for better performance
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

def invoke_create_google_docs_lambda(project_details):
    try:
        # Ensure this payload structure matches what the receiving Lambda expects
        payload = {
            'replacement_map': project_details  # Assuming project_details is the replacement map
        }
        response = lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName='create-google-docs-by-template',
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
            Payload=json.dumps(payload),
        )
        response_payload = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8"))
        logger.info(f"Response from create-google-docs-by-template: {response_payload}")
        return response_payload
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to invoke create-google-docs-by-template: {str(e)}")
        raise

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Extract the nested JSON string from the event
        json_str = event.get('params', {}).get('data')
        
        if not json_str:
            logger.error("No data provided in 'params.data'")
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps({'error': "No data provided"}),
                'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }

        # Parse the JSON string into a Python dictionary
        project_details = json.loads(json_str)
        
        # Log or process these details as needed
        logger.info(f"Received project details: {project_details}")
        
        # For demonstration, we'll extract a few specific fields and log them
        project_type = project_details.get("Project Type", "Unknown")
        project_title = project_details.get("Project Title", "No Title Provided")
        company_name = project_details.get("Customer Company Full Name", "No Company Provided")
        project_date = project_details.get("Date", "No Date Provided")
        project_solution = project_details.get("Proposed Solution", "No Proposed Solution Provided")
        project_objective = project_details.get("Objectives", "No Objectives Provided")
        project_sow = project_details.get("Scope of Work", "No Scope of Work Provided")
        
        logger.info(f"Project Type: {project_type}, Title: {project_title}, Company: {company_name}, Date: {project_date}, Proposed Solution: {project_solution}, Objectives: {project_objective}, Scope of Work: {project_sow}")
        
        # Send the placeholder information to create-google-docs-by-template lambda function
        create_docs_response = invoke_create_google_docs_lambda(project_details)
        
        # Return a success response
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Project details processed successfully'}),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
    except Exception as e:
        # Log and return an error response if an exception occurs
        logger.error(f"Error processing the request: {str(e)}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Failed to process the request'}),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }

This is the second lambda function used to create the google docs by template and replace the placeholder inside.
import json
import boto3
import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def download_credentials_from_s3(bucket_name, object_key):
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
        credentials_content = json.loads(response['Body'].read())
        logger.info("Successfully downloaded credentials from S3")
        return credentials_content
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error downloading credentials from S3: {e}")
        raise

def create_google_doc_from_template(template_doc_id, replacement_map):
    try:
        # Download credentials from S3
        bucket_name = '<bucket-name>'
        object_key = '<object-key>'
        credentials_content = download_credentials_from_s3(bucket_name, object_key)

        # Authenticate with Google Docs API with broader Drive scope
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            credentials_content,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']  # Adjusted scope here
        )
        service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
        logger.info("Authenticated with Google Docs API")

        # Create a copy of the template document
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
        copied_doc = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=template_doc_id, body={"name": 'Copy of Template'}).execute()
        new_doc_id = copied_doc.get('id')
        logger.info(f"Created copy of template document: {new_doc_id}")

        # Use the Google Docs API to replace placeholders in the new document
        requests = []
        for placeholder, value in replacement_map.items():
            requests.append({
                'replaceAllText': {
                    'containsText': {
                        'text': placeholder,
                        'matchCase': True
                    },
                    'replaceText': value,
                }
            })

        if requests:
            service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=new_doc_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
            logger.info("Replaced placeholders in the document")

        return new_doc_id
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error creating Google Doc from template: {e}")
        raise

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        if 'replacement_map' not in event:
            logger.error("replacement_map not provided in the event")
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps({'error': 'replacement_map not provided'})
            }

        replacement_map = event['replacement_map']
        template_doc_id = '<doc-id>'
        new_doc_id = create_google_doc_from_template(template_doc_id, replacement_map)
        logger.info(f"Successfully created new document: {new_doc_id}")

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({'documentId': new_doc_id})
        }
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Unhandled exception: {e}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Internal server error'})
        }


Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it?
